# Can a drywall screwdriver be used as a regular power screwdriver?

Tags: woodworking, powertools

I will be buying (or renting) a drywall screwdriver, I want to save a bit and have a tool that can be used for woodworking later, can it be used? Is it too low torque (I guess it is about 7 Nm) for driving screws on wood or steel?

I usually don't need to drive lag bolts or bigger screws, but I want a driver for general woodworking and I don't want to make final tighten by hand.

PS: I can find some other drywall screwdrivers that are about 13 Nm in torque, but they are kind of a chinese generic brand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've done it for several years.  However, drywall screwdrivers are considerably more expensive than regular power screwdrivers (battery or corded) because of the clutch that allows them to engage and disengage the torque upon press.  Once you get the hang of setting drywall screws and develop the sense of how deep to go without the guard (if you haven't already), you will be able to set them with a regular power drill and a Phillips bit.  It is not that hard.  Just in case you were contemplating a purchase of a drywall one, I would say you don't need it and should go for the simpler and cheaper solution of just using a regular power screwdriver or even just a drill with a Phillips bit.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: It does make sense, but from what I heard, driving drywall screws in metal studs are kind of troublesome without a drywall screwdriver since the screws penetrate so easily into the stud. I never hang drywall before, so I would like to go to the safer side and buy (or rent) a drywall screwdriver.

Comment: I've never used metal studs

Comment: I've had good luck using a high quality drywall screw bit like this one and a normal screwdriver: http://hydestore.com/hyde-tools-09039-drywall-adapter-bit.html

Comment: I've search around for this adaptor without luck. I also called some rental stores around here and they don't carry drywall screwguns, I guess I will have to settle with a drywall screwdriver and hope that it also serves my woodworking needs.

Comment: I'd rent the drywall screwdriver, but buy a good regular drill/driver for later use.